# Will layer standoffs cause problem with YDLIDAR X4 for SLAM?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to mount my EAI YDLIDAR X4 360 Degree 2D LIDAR on one of the lower layers of my home robot.  The LIDAR claims minimum ranging distance to be 0.12 meters (12cm), so if there are standoffs that hold the upper layers 1-2 cm from the unit will it cause a problem with localization or mapping?

ROS 2 Foxy
Ubuntu 20.04 Server
Raspberry Pi 3B+

/__________\
|  YDLIDAR  |
| ________ |
| Processor |
| ________ |
O..............O

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380176/will-layer-standoffs-cause-problem-with-ydlidar-x4-for-slam?/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2021-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should not be a problem.

If it causes any issues, you can use laser_filters, more specifically look here: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanBoxFilter

This will remove all points within a box, by setting it to NaN

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2021-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2